# How can I fix this for loop to print results inside an Array with Objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop, object

Rookie here, I have been breaking my head all day trying to figure this one out…

I have tried different approaches trying to figure this out and looking all over this site for some references, but I have come short and hit a roadblock.

This is my code currently:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import csvjson from 'csvjson'

const path = 'cyberBackgroundChecks/importer/assets/file.csv'

if (path && fs.existsSync(path)) {
    let file = fs.readFileSync(path);
    file = file.toString()
    const json = csvjson.toObject(file)

    let dataObject = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        if (json.length > 0) {
            dataObject['index'] = i
            dataObject['name'] = json[i]['OWNER 1 FIRST NAME'] ? json[i]['OWNER 1 FIRST NAME'] : json[i]['OWNER 1 LAST NAME']
            dataObject['streetAddress'] = json[i]['SITUS STREET ADDRESS']
            dataObject['city'] = json[i]['SITUS CITY']
            dataObject['state'] = json[i]['SITUS STATE']
        }
        console.log(dataObject)
    }
} else {
    console.log('The file does not exist');
}
```

I'm trying to get it to console log like this:

```
[
  {
    index: 0,
    name: 'Betsy',
    streetAddress: '1452 20th Ave',
    city: 'Seattle',
    state: 'WA'
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    name: 'Donald',
    streetAddress: '2702 NW 67th St',
    city: 'Seattle',
    state: 'WA'
  }
]
```

However, with my code, I can only get it to console log like this:

```
{
  index: 0,
  name: 'Betsy',
  streetAddress: '1452 20th Ave',
  city: 'Seattle',
  state: 'WA'
}
{
  index: 1,
  name: 'Donald',
  streetAddress: '2702 NW 67th St',
  city: 'Seattle',
  state: 'WA'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are printing data object 2 times inside the for loop. What you want to do is to create an array, add 2 data objects in the array and then print the array.

```
const dataObjectArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    let dataObject = {};
    dataObject['index'] = i;
    dataObject['name'] = json[i]['OWNER 1 FIRST NAME'] ? json[i]['OWNER 1 FIRST NAME'] : json[i]['OWNER 1 LAST NAME'];
    dataObject['streetAddress'] = json[i]['SITUS STREET ADDRESS'];
    dataObject['city'] = json[i]['SITUS CITY'];
    dataObject['state'] = json[i]['SITUS STATE'];
    dataObjectArr.push(dataObject);
}
console.log(dataObjectArr);
```

I removed this statement `if (json.length > 0)` because this will always be true as the loop already checks `json.length`.

A good practice is to end a line in the javascript code with semicolon.

Comment: Thank you so much! You've nailed it, and I fully understood what you explained to me.

I will start fixing my habit of not using the semicolon at the end of a line from now on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array where each item in the array is a `dataObject`, you need to create an array of `dataObjects` and `.push()` each `dataObject` into the array.

```
import fs from 'fs'
import csvjson from 'csvjson'

const path = 'cyberBackgroundChecks/importer/assets/file.csv'

if (path && fs.existsSync(path)) {
    let file = fs.readFileSync(path);
    file = file.toString()
    const json = csvjson.toObject(file)

    const dataObjects = []; // <--- new
    for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        const dataObject = {}; // <--- moved
        if (json.length > 0) {
            dataObject['index'] = i
            dataObject['name'] = json[i]['OWNER 1 FIRST NAME'] ? json[i]['OWNER 1 FIRST NAME'] : json[i]['OWNER 1 LAST NAME']
            dataObject['streetAddress'] = json[i]['SITUS STREET ADDRESS']
            dataObject['city'] = json[i]['SITUS CITY']
            dataObject['state'] = json[i]['SITUS STATE']
        }
        dataObjects.push(dataObject); // <--- new
    }
} else {
    console.log('The file does not exist');
}
console.log(dataObjects); // <--- new
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining data already is very useful whenever studying data structure. Your code is well written and just a few things are needed. Define an array for putting the objects created by the for loop and code `push` in the for loop to put the objects.

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import csvjson from 'csvjson'

const path = 'cyberBackgroundChecks/importer/assets/file.csv'

if (path && fs.existsSync(path)) {
    let file = fs.readFileSync(path);
    file = file.toString()
    const json = csvjson.toObject(file)

    let anArray = [] /// for putting dataObject in
    let dataObject = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        if (json.length > 0) {
            dataObject['index'] = i
            dataObject['name'] = json[i]['OWNER 1 FIRST NAME'] ? json[i]['OWNER 1 FIRST NAME'] : json[i]['OWNER 1 LAST NAME']
            dataObject['streetAddress'] = json[i]['SITUS STREET ADDRESS']
            dataObject['city'] = json[i]['SITUS CITY']
            dataObject['state'] = json[i]['SITUS STATE']
        }
        anArray.push(dataObject) // push the obeject into the array
        //console.log(dataObject)
    }
console.log(anArray) // then log the array the objects are put out of for loop. 
} else {
    console.log('The file does not exist');
}
```